# Use Laravel/Passport as OAUTH2-provider and log in a user using socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite, laravel-7

I would like to login an user that exists on one Laravel-app on another site.

- *Laravel-Prodiver*: SPA Laravel-App using Passport
- *Laravel-Client*: SPA Laravel-App using Socialite with passport-diver (https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/providers/laravel-passport.html)

On *Laravel-Prodiver* I created a new OAuth-client:

```
mysql> select * from oauth_clients;
+----+---------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | name                              | secret                                   | redirect                                  | personal_access_client | password_client | revoked | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |    NULL | Accounting Personal Access Client | 1231231231231231231231231231231231231231 | http://localhost                          |                      1 |               0 |       0 | 2020-02-09 14:24:32 | 2020-02-09 14:24:32 |
|  2 |    NULL | Accounting Password Grant Client  | 1231231231231231231231231231231231231231 | http://laravel-client.test/oauth/callback |                      0 |               1 |       0 | 2020-02-09 14:24:32 | 2020-02-09 14:24:32 |
|  3 |    NULL | Password Grant Client             | 1231231231231231231231231231231231231231 | http://localhost                          |                      0 |               1 |       0 | 2020-04-14 12:30:21 | 2020-04-14 12:30:21 |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

On Laravel-prodiver I added `Passport::routes();` to `AuthServiceProvider`.

```
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user/{id?}                          | api.user.view                        | App\Http\Controllers\UserApiController@view                               | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/authorize                         | passport.authorizations.authorize    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize       | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/authorize                         | passport.authorizations.approve      | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ApproveAuthorizationController@approve  | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/authorize                         | passport.authorizations.deny         | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\DenyAuthorizationController@deny        | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/clients                           | passport.clients.store               | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@store                  | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/clients                           | passport.clients.index               | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@forUser                | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/clients/{client_id}               | passport.clients.destroy             | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@destroy                | web,auth     |
|        | PUT      | oauth/clients/{client_id}               | passport.clients.update              | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@update                 | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/personal-access-tokens            | passport.personal.tokens.store       | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@store     | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/personal-access-tokens            | passport.personal.tokens.index       | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@forUser   | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/personal-access-tokens/{token_id} | passport.personal.tokens.destroy     | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@destroy   | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/scopes                            | passport.scopes.index                | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ScopeController@all                     | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/token                             |                                      | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken        | throttle     |
|        | POST     | oauth/token/refresh                     | passport.token.refresh               | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/tokens                            | passport.tokens.index                | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/tokens/{token_id}                 | passport.tokens.destroy              | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | {any}                                   |                                      | App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController                                | web          |
```

So if I now open `http://laravel-provider.test/oauth/authorize` I am being redirected to my home page.

If I add a route without the `auth` middleware like this:

```
Route::get('oauth/authorize', '\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize');
Route::get('/{any}', 'ApplicationController')->where('any', '.*');
```

I can access the route and I am able to create a Socialite-redirection like this:

```
return Socialite::with('laravelpassport')->setConfig($config)
        ->redirect();
```

In this case I am getting this error:

```
Error
Call to a member function getKey() on null
http://laravel-provider.test/oauth/authorize?client_id=2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%laravel-client.test%2Foauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=&state=4TUCV7HLfSROjoF1AShmseQZybRB8XbuKX9vM1mZ
```

This is the part where the error is triggered:

```
**
     * Find a valid token for the given user and client.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $user
     * @param  \Laravel\Passport\Client  $client
     * @return \Laravel\Passport\Token|null
     */
    public function findValidToken($user, $client)
    {
        return $client->tokens()
                      ->whereUserId($user->getKey())
                      ->where('revoked', 0)
                      ->where('expires_at', '>', Carbon::now())
                      ->latest('expires_at')
                      ->first();
    }
```

My questions are:

- What am I doing wrong here? Why is my route not callable? Am I right assuming that the auth-middleware does not work here?
- How can I "open" Passport to allow users log in on third-party-websites?
- Why is the `auth` middleware default here and how can I assure that people can log in using Socialite?